# Making super() work in Python's urllib2.Request

Tags: python, request, urllib2, super, new-style-class

This afternoon I spent several hours trying to find a bug in my custom extension to `urllib2.Request`. The problem was, as I found out, the usage of `super(ExtendedRequest, self)`, since `urllib2.Request` is (I'm on Python 2.5) still an old style class, where the use of `super()` is not possible.

The most obvious way to create a new class with both features,

```
class ExtendedRequest(object, urllib2.Request):
    def __init__():
        super(ExtendedRequest, self).__init__(...)
```

doesn't work. Calling it, I'm left with `AttributeError: type` raised by `urllib2.Request.__getattr__()`. Now, before I start and copy'n paste the whole `urllib2.Request` class from /usr/lib/python just to rewrite it as

```
class Request(object):
```

has anyone an idea, how I could achieve this in a more elegant way? (With *this* being to have a *new-style* class based on `urllib2.Request` with working support for `super()`.)

**Edit:** By the way: the AttributeError mentioned:

```
>>> class ExtendedRequest(object, urllib2.Request):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super(ExtendedRequest, self).__init__('http://stackoverflow.com')
...
>>> ABC = ExtendedRequest ()
>>> d = urllib2.urlopen(ABC)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 373, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 241, in get_type
    if self.type is None:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 218, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, attr
AttributeError: type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine since the hierarchy is simple

```
class ExtendedRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def __init__(self,...):
        urllib2.Request.__init__(self,...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know that. Actually, I'm doing just this at the moment. However, I wanted to utilize the power of super() in some aspects, such as multiple inheritance.

Comment: The whole hierarchy has to be new style for `super` to work correctly

Comment: yes it's a pity that urllib2 isn't using newstyle classes. I wonder why they did that

Answer (score 1):

Using super may not always be the best-practice. There are many difficulties with using super. Read James Knight's http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/ for examples.

That link shows (among other issues) that

1. Superclasses must use super if their subclasses do

   The `__init__` signatures of all subclasses that use super should match. You must pass all arguments you receive on to the super function. Your `__init__` must be prepared to call any other class's `__init__` method in the hierarchy.

   Never use positional arguments in `__init__`

In your situation, each of the above critera is violated.

James Knight also says,

> The only situation in which super()
>   can actually be helpful is when you
>   have diamond inheritance. And even
>   then, it is often not as helpful as
>   you might have thought.

The conditions under which super can be used correctly are sufficiently onerous, that I think super's usefulness is rather limited. Prefer the Composition design pattern over subclassing. Avoid diamond inheritance if you can. If you control the object hierarchy from top (object) to bottom, and use super consistently, then you are okay. But since you don't control the entire class hierarchy in this case, I'd suggest you abandon using `super`.

Comment: Meanwhile I browsed through some of the related questions in the right column and found James Knight's article, too. Although I still think, that `super()` is a mighty tool, I start to get a grip on its disadvantages. Thanks for pointing it out in detail!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to pass the self parameter to definition of **init** in your sample.
Try this one:

```
class ExtendedRequest(object, urllib2.Request):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExtendedRequest, self).__init__(self)
```

I tested it and it seems to work okey:

```
>>> x = ExtendedRequest()
>>> super(ExtendedRequest, x)
<super: <class 'ExtendedRequest'>, <ExtendedRequest object>>
```

Comment: Yes, but when you try to call any method on the `<super>` object, it raises the AttributeError.